# AWS CDK how to create Glue Studio Connectors

Tags: aws-glue, aws-cdk

I need to create a custom Spark connector for a Glue Job however I can only find information on creating Database Connections and not the connectors via CDK. Is this even possible?

Comment: I hope cdk documentation will help you . ( aws glue construct is still in alpha .)
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-glue-alpha-readme.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-glue-alpha.PythonSparkJobExecutableProps.html

Comment: It does not :( There is no mention at all on how to create marketplace connectors.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did. I created the marketplace connection manually to pull the properties using the command.

```
aws glue get-connection --catalog-id <aws_account_id> --name ElasticsearchGlueConnector
```

I got the following output for Elasticsearch

```
{
"Connection": {
    "Name": "ElasticsearchGlueConnector",
    "Description": "",
    "ConnectionType": "MARKETPLACE",
    "MatchCriteria": [
        "Connection",
        "Elasticsearch Connector 7.13.4 for AWS Glue 3.0"
    ],
    "ConnectionProperties": {
        "CONNECTOR_CLASS_NAME": "org.elasticsearch.spark.sql",
        "CONNECTOR_TYPE": "Spark",
        "CONNECTOR_URL": "https://709825985650.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/amazon-web-services/glue/elasticsearch:7.13.4-glue3.0-2"
    },
    "PhysicalConnectionRequirements": {
        "SubnetId": "xxxxx",
        "SecurityGroupIdList": [
            "xxxxxx"
        ],
        "AvailabilityZone": "xxxx"
    },
    "CreationTime": 1664056085.788,
    "LastUpdatedTime": 1664056085.788
}
```

}

I then used this information to create connection through CDK and it was successful.

```
      new Connection(this, 'elasticSearchConnection', {
        type: new ConnectionType('MARKETPLACE'),
        connectionName: 'ElasticsearchGlueConnector',
        matchCriteria: [
            "Connection",
            "Elasticsearch Connector 7.13.4 for AWS Glue 3.0"
        ],
        description: 'ElasticSearch Connector for AWS Glue Jobs',
        securityGroups: [glueSecurityGroup],
        subnet: subnet,
        properties: {
            'CONNECTOR_CLASS_NAME': 'org.elasticsearch.spark.sql',
            'CONNECTOR_TYPE': 'Spark',
            'CONNECTOR_URL': 'https://709825985650.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/amazon-web-services/glue/elasticsearch:7.13.4-glue3.0-2'
        },
    });
```